# I have a problem for integral complex functions $\frac{1}{z}$ and $\frac{1}{z^2}$ respectively.

Tags: complex-analysis

When I study Complex analysis ,I find a interesting phenomenon.

If we integral $\frac{1}{z}$ and $\frac{1}{z^2}$,we will find that:
$$\int_{C}\frac{1}{z}dz=2\pi i$$
and
$$\int_{C}\frac{1}{z^2}dz=0$$
$C$ is a circle centered at $0$.

And more generally
$$\int_{C_r(z_0)}\frac{1}{(z-z_0)^k} dz= 0,\text{if $k\ge2$}$$

My problem is that functions $\frac{1}{z}$ and $\frac{1}{z^2}$ both have singularity at $0$, i.e. they are holomorphic on closure of $C$ but except $0$. In this case , Cauchy's theorem is lose efficacy.However only $\int_{C}\frac{1}{z}dz\ne 0$.I think it's amazing!

Can you tell me the deeper reason?

Comment: If you differentiate the Cauchy formula $n$ times you get $$
f^{(n)} (w) = \frac{{n!}}{{2\pi i}}\oint_{(w^ +  )} {\frac{{f(z)}}{{(z - w)^{n + 1} }}dz} .
$$ Another way to look at it is to say that the residue is $0$ for $w^{-2}$. Look up the residue theorem.

Comment: I'd argue the "deeper" reason is that the antiderivative of $x^n$ is $\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}$ for any $n \neq -1$, but is equal to $\log x$ for $n = -1$. In turn this comes from the fact the limit as $h \mapsto 0$ of $\frac{(x+h)^n - x^n}{h}$ is given by a logarithm in the case $n = -1$, but is a power function otherwise. I view this phenomona as having to do with the restriction of harmonic functions in two or less dimensions, but there are plenty of equivalent explanations.

Comment: Well, it's that along with the fact $\log z$ is not holomorphic on any deleted neighborhood of zero while $z^n$ is for any $z \in \mathbb Z$. That the answer is $2 \pi i$ specifically just comes from the distance between covering sheets of the Riemann Surface for $\log z$ (i.e. the $i$ is there because of the vertical covering, and the $2\pi$ is just the length around the circle)